# replace() is not a function nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, boolean

I am greeting response from mysql db and has bool value in it and i want to change 1= True and 0= false ,  here is my code. but replace function is not working :

TypeError: data[i].defaultstatus.replace is not a function

Here is my code :

```
     var data= "select * from table"

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        detail[i] = {
            "id":data[i].id,
          "Enabled":data[i].defaultstatus.replace('1', 'True' || '0','false'),
          "CreationDate":data[i].created_at,
          "ModificationDate":data[i].updated_at
          }
      }
     resolve(detail)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think The problem is how you are applying the **replace** function
check what the value is before calling the replace function

try this :

```
   var data= "select * from table"
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        detail[i] = {
            "id":data[i].id,
             "Enabled": data[i].defaultstatus==1? data[i].defaultstatus.replace('1','True'):data[i].defaultstatus.replace('0', 'False')'
          "CreationDate":data[i].created_at,
          "ModificationDate":data[i].updated_at
          }
      }
     resolve(detail)
```

**OR**

eliminate the replace function all together

```
    var data= "select * from table"
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        detail[i] = {
            "id":data[i].id,
          "Enabled": data[i].defaultstatus==1? 'true':'False
          "CreationDate":data[i].created_at,
          "ModificationDate":data[i].updated_at
          }
      }
     resolve(detail)
```